# Celery groups and chains

Tags: python, celery

I need to sort some tasks in Celery that some of them should as a single task and some should work parallel and when the tasks in the group completed, it should pass the next one:

```
chain(
    task1.s(),
    task2.s(),
    group(task3.s(), task4.s()), 
    group(task5.s(), task6.s(), task7.s()), 
    task7.s()
).delay()
```

But I think what did I do is wrong. Any body have idea how to do it?

Also, I don't care about sending the result of each task to the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one finally worked:

```
chain(
    task1.s(),
    task2.s(),
    chord([task3.s(), task4.s()], body=task_result.s(), immutable=True), 
    chord([task5.s(), task6.s(), task7.s()], body=task_result.s(), immutable=True), 
    task7.s()
).delay()
```

Comment: Excellent! I'll test it tomorrow.
I've been struggling on it for a day today. ha-ha.

Comment: what is task_result ?

Comment: Example of function task_result().
``` 
@app.task(name='FINISH_GROUP') def task_result(): # might need parameter task_result(results): print('TEST: finish_group({}) -> {}'.format(nb, results))
```

Comment: ref, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137592/celery-launch-chord-callback-after-its-associated-body

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a chord, ie where you execute tasks in parallel and have a callback into another task when the parallel tasks are finished: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords

So you might have to change it something like:
chain(task1.s(), task2.s(), chord(task3.s(), task4.s())(chord(task5.s(), task6.s(), task7.s())(task7.s())))

Also, chains/groups etc always return the results and pass them on to the child task(s) so you have to model the task arguments accordingly.

As it's quite a complex workflow, you might be better off calling the next task from with the previous task (like calling task2.s().delay() at the end of task1) - but I guess there's no way around modelling the chord.

Comment: Yes Björn, I have also thought about chord, so I think for returning the results of the tasks in the chord, I can use a dummy task. So, will what's within the chord also work with many workers (multi-threaded) such as in Group?

Edit: Well, it seems like parallel (Now you can use a chord to calculate each addition step in parallel, and then get the sum of the resulting numbers)